# Solve the equation $|2x^2+x-1|=|x^2+4x+1|$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, absolute-value

Find the sum of all the solutions of the equation  $|2x^2+x-1|=|x^2+4x+1|$

Though I tried to solve it in desmos.com and getting the requisite answer but while solving it manually it is getting very lengthy.

I tried to construct the two parabola and mirror image the region below y axis but still getting it is getting complicated.

> Is there any easy method to solve it and get the sum of all the solutions ?

Comment: [Vieta's formula.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas)

Comment: Note:  $0$ is a root

Comment: @EclipseSun We can use Vieta's formula, but to solve a quadratic equation should also not be a real challenge.

Comment: How can a question showing an effort AND context receive $4$ close-votes and $3$ down-votes ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We are asked for the sum of the roots; we don't necessarily have to find the roots.

Squaring, we get $(2x^2+x-1)^2=(x^2+4x-1)^2$.

So $4x^4+4x^3...=x^4+8x^3...$.

So $\color{blue}3x^4-\color{blue}4x^3....=0$.

By [Vieta's formulas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas), the answer is $\dfrac43$.

Comment: inspired by [Dr. Sonnhard Graubner](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/175066/dr-sonnhard-graubner) (squaring) and [Eclipse Sun](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/119490/eclipse-sun) (Vieta's formulas)

Comment: You can even do with $4x^4+4x^3+\cdots=x^4+8x^3+\cdots$.

Comment: Yes @YvesDaoust; I thought of that after I posted

Answer (score 7):

Hint : Solve the two equations $$2x^2+x-1=x^2+4x+1$$ and $$2x^2+x-1=-x^2-4x-1$$

Comment: And the conditions for that?

Comment: Since we have $|a|=|b|$ if and only if $a=b$ or $a=-b$ exactly the solutions of those equations solve the given equation.

Comment: Better is, i think, to square both sides of the equation.

Comment: @Dr.SonnhardGraubner This gives an equation of degree $4$. I prefer this approach.

Comment: Which can be factorized!

Comment: True, but what is better compared to solve two equations with degree $2$ , which we have to do after the factorization anyway ?

Comment: @Peter: in fact, factorization is unnecessary. All you have to do is to compute the fourth and third degree coefficients.

Comment: @YvesDaoust I know because only the sum has to be determined. But my approach is already easy enough and answers the question whether there is an easy solution.

Answer (score 3):

The expressions between the absolute value bars have the same or opposite signs. Hence there are two independent cases (by addition and subtraction):

$$3x^2+5x=0$$ and $$x^2-3x-2=0.$$

Then by Vieta,

$$-\frac53+3.$$

---

For complete rigor, one should show that no root is repeated. This is true, because the polynomials have no double root, and their $\text{gcd}$ is $1$.

Answer (score 2):

$$
|2x^2+x-1|=|x^2+4x+1|\\
(2x^2+x-1)^2=(x^2+4x+1)^2\\
(2x^2+x-1)^2-(x^2+4x+1)^2=0\\
[(2x^2+x-1)+(x^2+4x+1)]\cdot[(2x^2+x-1)-(x^2+4x+1)]=0\\
(3x^2+5x)\cdot(x^2-3x-2)=0\\
x\cdot(3x+5)\cdot(x^2-3x-2)=0\\
Solving\space for\space all\space cases,\space we\space get:\\
x=0\\
x=-\frac{5}{3}\\
x=\frac{3\pm\sqrt{17}}{2}
$$

Answer (score 1):

Squaring and factorizing we get
$$x(3x+5)(x^2-3x-2)=0$$
The solutions are given by $$x=-\frac{5}{3}\lor x=0\lor x=\frac{1}{2} \left(3-\sqrt{17}\right)\lor
   x=\frac{1}{2} \left(3+\sqrt{17}\right)$$

Comment: And the conditions for that ?